# How to find out what is blocking a port in Centos 7?

Tags: firewall, centos7, port

I'm trying to make a mailserver with postfix/dovecot but I'm stuck. The problem is I cannot connect to some of the ports I want open, for example `587`. As far as I can tell the port is open and listening, and the firewall has the port opened. I know that some years ago the ISP blocked all ports except those explicitly requested as opened, but now they swear that they're not blocking anything anymore.

If I try to connect locally via `telnet localhost 587` I get a proper connection. The same if I replace `localhost` with the external IP address (don't know if it matters).

Here's some diagnostic information showing that it should work:

```
> netstat -an4
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*

> firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp5s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 21/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 49152-65534/tcp 25/tcp 110/tcp 143/tcp 993/tcp 995/tcp 465/tcp 587/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

> ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 scope global noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And last but not least, the raw dump from `iptables` - this one I'm not skilled enough to decipher, but perhaps someone can notice a problem there.

```
> iptables --list -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 match-set fail2ban-sshd src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
IN_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
IN_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:49152:65534 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

My question is - after all this, is there still *some* doubt that my server might be blocking the connections on its own? If yes, how do I find that out? Or is this conclusive enough that I need to go raise hell with the ISP?

Comment: Most ISPs would block port 25 at least as a measure against spam and injury to the ISP’s mail reputation. Your ISP may also do this for other mail-related ports too. If in doubt, you can check using tcpdump on your firewall host; even if that machine’s firewall would drop it, you will still it with tcpdump. Then go have a friendly chat with your ISP.

Comment: @CameronKerr - This is a server hosted in a data center (admittedly not exactly first rate, but still). Ironically, port 25 is open and working well. `tcpdump` - I'll try it.

Comment: OK, what happens when you try to connect remotely to one of the ports? This important detail doesn't seem to be in your question. And you didn't actually post the IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I try to connect with Putty (raw connection), and it just times out. For other working ports (like 110) the connection is instantaneous and I see a greeting from the server. The actual IP - well... do you really need to know that? I was kinda trying to keep it anonymous, but if you say that you can divine something from that, I'll post it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Ahh, and just so that you know there isn't something on my side - connecting to another mail server that I know of (but not under my control), the same port `587`, I get a greeting message also almost instantaneously.

Comment: Well, your server's firewall looks fine, and if you can reach port 587 on other servers, then it probably isn't your home connection. That leaves... something in between? [We recommend _not_ obfuscating anything](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) unless it's really necessary (like passwords). In this case it may very well be helpful to know the real IP address. There might be something strange about your datacenter that someone else knows about, for instance. Or someone might be able to come up with something I haven't thought of.

Comment: Well, OK then. The hostname is `21.lv` and you can get the IP from that - `159.148.97.35`. IPv6 isn't really set up, I don'[ t know where that comes from. Ignore it anyway.

Comment: Iin any case, if you can, you should `nmap` your own IP from outside and see what the results are.

Comment: I ran `nmap` on your IP address myself. It appears that there might be an external firewall, provided by the datacenter, not on your server. Are you sure that the datacenter is not providing a firewall? Instead of a connection timeout, some ports returned a refused connection (ICMP admin prohibited) from 159.148.70.202, which appears to be one of their addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Well, we've been pointing fingers at each other for a few days now. But looks like I'm right and they need to recheck their network setup! :) Thanks for the info, if my latest email still bears no fruit, I'll run the nmap myself and provide them with the output (I only haven't done so yet because I've never used nmap before).

Comment: To save you a long trip through man pages, I suggest `map -d -d -O -P0 -sS -T4 159.148.97.35`. The output is extensive and you may not understand most of it but may be helpful for network admins trying to find the trouble.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks, I was about to ask for that! :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Happy ending! They did find their own misconfiguration after all, no need for `nmap`. :) Do you think I should delete this question? Doesn't seem like it will be useful to anyone else in the future, and there are no answers to accept...